# Recursive javascript function returns the root element

Tags: javascript

I have a tree-like structure with a `node` function and recursive `search` function that must return the node matched against an url, like:

```
var node = function(url) {
    var instance = this;

    this.url = url;
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];

    this.search = function(url) {
        if (url === instance.url)
            return this;
        else {
            for (var c = 0; c < instance.children.length; c++) {
                if (instance.children[c].search(url) !== null)
                    return instance.children[c];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I know the recursive function is wrong, it always returns the root node. How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

`this` is kind of goofy in JS.  You would *think* that when you have

```
var instance = this
```

that it shouldn't matter whether you return `instance` or `this`, but as it turns out, if you return `instance`, your code works, but if you return `this`, it doesn't.

Using `return this`:

```js
var node = function(url) {
    var instance = this;
    this.url = url;
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];

    this.search = function(url) {
        if (url === instance.url) {
            return this;
        }
        else {
            for (var c = 0; c < instance.children.length; c++) {
                if (instance.children[c].search(url) !== null)
                    return instance.children[c];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    return { url, parent, children, search };
}


const root = node('root');
root.children.push(node('child-A'));
console.log(root.search('child-A').url);
```

Using `return instance`:

```js
var node = function(url) {
    var instance = this;
    this.url = url;
    this.parent = null;
    this.children = [];

    this.search = function(url) {
        if (url === instance.url) {
            return instance;
        }
        else {
            for (var c = 0; c < instance.children.length; c++) {
                if (instance.children[c].search(url) !== null)
                    return instance.children[c];
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    return { url, parent, children, search };
}


const root = node('root');
root.children.push(node('child-A'));
console.log(root.search('child-A').url);
```

Comment: It didnt fix it for me. I fixed it by creating a temporary var: `var node = instance_.children[c].search(url);`